# ExpandableListView with child item have html text

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I want to add html text in item child, but I don't know how to do in method setChildData. Any idea? Thank from help. I can not add html text in add a function can be changed to setText somehow?
My code:

```
public class EcologicalInformationActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{

        private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); // you can use (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list)

            expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
            expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
            expandableList.setClickable(true);

            setGroupParents();
            setChildData();

            MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

            adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
            expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
            expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setGroupParents() { 
            parentItems.add("Wątpliwości? skontaktuj się z nami");
            parentItems.add("Artykuł 3");

        }

        public void setChildData() {

            child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Infolinia:"+
"tel. 58 731 64 64 (czynna pn-pt 7.00-15.00)"+
"koszt jak za połączenia lokalne"+

"Biuro Obsługi Klienta"+
"Gospodarka Odpadami Komunalnymi"+
"Zarząd Dróg i Zieleni w Gdańsku"+
"ul. Partyzantów 36 (budynek D)"+
"e-mail: bok@czystemiasto.gdansk.pl");
            childItems.add(child);

            // Artykuł 3

            child = new ArrayList<String>();
            child.add("Wiadomość3");
            childItems.add(child);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set some text to child view in your custom adapter in getChildView method.
Here's an example: http://michieldemey.be/blog/how-to-use-the-expandablelistview-in-android/